# How to correctly monitor a Java Batch process?

Tags: java, batch-processing, snmp

I am trying to find a way to monitor the progress of a Java Batch Process.
My first thought is receive the start event that posts every task to be done to a queue and asynchronously subscribe that queue from another process that for each message processed does whet must be done, not coupling the code.

I must have also a way to send notifications if something unexpected occurs.  So, my idea is to use SNMP (send SNMP trap to systems able to receive it) to signal if my batch process fails.  Is it a correct thought?  Any ideas?

Comment: What batch implementation and environment are you running in?   The RI in SE?  An application server?

Comment: No specific batch implementation.  It is a queue publish subscribe process running over an application server.

Comment: Was trying to get a feel for what components/products you might already be using.  Often this would be handled by a [job scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software) layer around your Java Batch application.

Comment: Basically a job scheduler is a "fire and forget" approach.  What I mean is something that enables to check if the process is running fine.  My thoughts are around snmp and jmx.  Ideas?

Comment: The question is not really a good fit for the format of Stack Overflow, due to being a bit unspecific.